# Combing odd and even regular expression to regular grammar?

Tags: regex, prolog, grammar, dcg

I have this class that I need to write regular grammar for. The grammar is  {a,b,c} where there are an odd number of a's and c's, but an even number of b's.

Examples of good strings:

- babc
- abcb
- cbba
- accaccac
- ac

Bad strings

- babcb
- abc
- cbbca
- accacca
- aa
- *empty string

My regex for even b's is `b∗(ab∗ab∗)∗b∗` (I don't know where to include c)

My regex for odd a's is `(c|a(b|c)*a)*a(b|c)*`

My regex for odd c's is `(c|a(b|c)*c)*c(b|c)*`

I'm thinking that a regular grammar would look something like this:

```
s -> [a], a
s -> [c], c

a -> [a], a
a -> [b], b
a -> [c], c

b -> [b]
b -> [b], b
b -> [a], a
b -> [c], c

c -> [c], c
c -> [a], a
c -> [b], b
```

I think it's evident that I'm very lost. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your regex for even b's matches even a's.

Comment: I don't know your notation but I can draw you a DFA (with 8 states) for it.

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs the corresponding automaton should accept! E.g. "aaabbc" etc...

Comment: Your regex for odd `c`s doesn’t seem to match any simple concept except that `b` cannot be first and there must be at least two `c`s between any two `a`s.

Comment: @repeat I think order doesn’t matter and `ababccbacb` would work; that is, `a^k₀b^bm₀c^n₀a^k₁b^bm₁c^n₁...` where the ks add up to an odd number, the ms add up to an even number, and the ns add up to an odd number.

Comment: @repeat Yes it can; one of us is misreading the expression I wrote. None of the exponents, either for the same letter or for different letters, need to be the same. In English, that’s “Some number of `a`s, `b`s, and `c`s, in any order, where the total number of `a`s is odd, the total number of `b`s is even, and the total number of `c`s is odd”. As melpomene says, it can be made in a DFA of 8 states. EDIT: It’s me; I made a typo in the expression. All my `b^bmᵢ`s should have been `b^mᵢ`.

Comment: @melpomene that would be awesome if you could provide a DFA :)

Comment: @repeat added :)

Comment: Just making sure: I'm guessing an even number of `b`s doesn't include 0 of them.

Comment: @CAustin 0 b's is considered even and a'okay.

Comment: This is one of those problems that is easiest to solve by starting with a DFA for the language and then converting that to an RE.  The DFA is trivial with 8 states, tracking whether the number of a's b's and c's is odd or even (start in the even-even-even state, and only the odd-even-odd state is accepting).

Comment: DFA: https://i.imgur.com/wESOrhA.png (all transitions are bidirectional)

Comment: I think that you should take a look at automaton/8 of Library clpb of SWI-Prolog

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution in SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

odd_even(Lst) :-
    variables_signature(Lst, Sigs),
    automaton(Sigs, _, Sigs,
              % start in s, end in i
              [source(s), sink(i)],
              % if we meet 0, counter A of a is incremented of one modulo 2
              % the others are unchanged
              [arc(s, 0, s, [(A+1) mod 2, B, C]),
               arc(s, 1, s, [A, (B+1)mod 2, C]),
               arc(s, 2, s, [A, B, (C+1) mod 2]),
               arc(s, 0, i, [(A+1) mod 2, B, C]),
               arc(s, 1, i, [A, (B+1)mod 2, C]),
               arc(s, 2, i, [A, B, (C+1) mod 2])],
              % name of counters
              [A, B, C], 
              % initial values of counters
              [0, 0, 0], 
              % needed final values of counters
              [1,0,1]).

% replace a with 0, b with 1, c with 2
variables_signature(Lst, Sigs) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^(X = a -> Y = 0; (X = b -> Y = 1; Y = 2)), Lst, Sigs).
```

Example :

```
?- odd_even([a,c,c,a,c,c,a,c]).
true.

?- odd_even([a,c,c,a,c,c,a]).
false.
```

Comment: ~ impurity in variables_signature

Comment: @false : I don't understand what you mean with "~impurity" :-( . I'm not sure to really understand "purity concept" of Prolog :-(((

Comment: Take your own example: `odd_even([a,c,c,a,c,c,a,c]).` succeeds. Perfect. Now, lets try a generalized query: `odd_even([a,c,c,a,c,c,a,X]).` which incorrectly fails.

Comment: Ok, I got it ! Another challenge.

Comment: Just another suggestion: Maybe it is best to have your actual relation over a list of 0..2 in a separate predicate. After all the variable_signature thing enforces a trivial mode - just groundness. But the automaton constraint is so much more versatile!